# Swift Compiler Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'name'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors, ios9

I tried to include a class called 'name' and I got an error:

```
Swift Compiler Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'name'
```

The class exists and doesn't contain any compile errors.

Comment: A snippet of code showing exactly how you declared the class would be very helpful, especially to others who come here facing the same issue.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There could be a few possible issues.

1. One of the classes has a **Testing target** and other one doesn't. You have to even include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them.
2. If it's Objective C class, check that the class is in ObjectiveC bridging header file.
3. If it's NSManagedObject subclass. Add `@objc(className)` before the class declaration.
4. If it's part of a different framework, make sure that the class or function is `public`

Comment: For example, if one class has a Testing target and second one doesn't

Comment: Hmm, I only have one target, the build target, and it still doesn't work. Any more tips Vojtech?

Comment: This was driving me nuts.  The red "error dots" would show up on the left side of the code with the error message underneath.  If I compiled/ran the code -- the red dots would go away!  If I touched the file (AppDelegate in my case), the red dots would re-appear.  Didn't realize that because I had included AppDelegate in unit testing target, that it was the test target and not the app target that was bringing back the red dots.  So, either move routines used in unit tests into classes that are included in test targets, or add your other classes also to be used in unit tests.

Comment: I had the same problem today, and both classes had the same target membership. I then unchecked, then rechecked, the target memberships in both and the problem went away.

Answer (score 6):

I had this one too. You will probably find that your first class is included in your testing module and that "name" isn't. Simply, if you include a class in testing, then every class that it references has to be in testing.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too. I was trying to reference Class 1 within the code in Class 2. My problem was that Class 2 had target memberships in A and B, and Class 1 only had Target Memberships in Class A.

You can fix this by opening the Utilities Tab (farthest right button on the top bar of the Xcode window), and make sure that the same boxes are checked for both classes in the Target Membership subsection.

Answer (score 1):

Got problem solved by

**Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Adding the class file**

Answer (score -1):

Add one more to the list.

5. If it is part of another framework, make certain that the "Build Active Architecture Only" settings are the same.

Comment: With that settings, you will not be able to release the app. Make sure to use framework that supports your architectures.

Comment: Not true. You can release the app as long as "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No" for "Release". I experienced the "Use of unresolved identifier" error when my framework had it set to "Yes" for "Debug" but my app had "No" for "Debug".