# 'unresolved identifier' for return value of Type Method in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to access the return value from a Type Method in one file from another file. To wit:

file_1:

```
class LetterView: UIView {
    class func testFunction() -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(100,200)
    }
}
```

file_2:

```
class AnotherClass {
    func callTestFunction() {
        var result = LetterView.testFunction()
        print("- breakpoint here - ")
    }
}
```

I get an Unresolved Identifier error on `var result` if I put a breakpoint in the debugger and do a `po result`. However if I change the return type of `testFunction()` to be an `Int` (say 2) and return that instead, then the function call works as expected. Color me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Is the second file importing UIKit as well? Also, you should update your example from `function` to `func`.  This all works in the playground which leads to UIKit missing.

Comment: Both files import UIKit, and thanks for catching the 'function' typo. FWIW, the workaround here is to return a tuple, and turn that into a CGSize at the other end of the call.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few possible issues.

One of the classes has a Testing target and other one doesn't. You have to even include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them.

If it's Objective C class, check that the class is in ObjectiveC bridging header file.

If it's NSManagedObject subclass. Add @objc(className) before the class declaration.

If it's part of a different framework, make sure that the class or function is public

This is the original answer link : [Swift Compiler Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099111/swift-compiler-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-name)

Comment: There's no Testing target, so that's not it. Both classes are pure Swift, nothing to do with Core Data, and they're both in the same framework. I keep looking at the fact that the only return type that fails is a CG ... type, and wonder about that. Hmmm ...