# Refreshing gives Error that "found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, watchkit

I'm moving this `getCloudKit` function from `ViewController.swift` to `Lay.swift` so I can keep everything in a single class.

```
var objects = [Lay]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.getCloudKit()
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    self.objects.removeAll()
    self.getCloudKit()
}

func getCloudKit() {

    let now = NSDate()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TimeDate > %@", now)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "TimeDate", ascending: true)

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: “lay”, predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { 
            for lay in results! {
                let newlay = Lay()

                newLay.tColor = lay["tColor"] as! String
                newLay.timeDate = lay["TimeDate"] as! AnyObject
                newLay.matchup = lay["Matchup"] as! String

                let applicationDict = ["tColor" : newLay.tColor, "Matchup" : newLay.matchup]
                let transfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)

                self.objects.append(newLay)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

The **problem** is when I move it (and the necessary related code):

- **Error in `Lay.swift`** on `TableViewController().refreshControl!.endRefreshing()`
  saying *"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
  Optional value"*
- Need to put my **`WCSession: transferUserInfo` code from `getCloudKit` in my `AppDelegate.swift`, but keep getting errors** when I try

New `ViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    Lay().getCloudKit()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return Lay().objects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let object = Lay().objects[indexPath.row];
    if let label = cell.textLabel{
        label.text = object.matchup
    }

    return cell
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    Lay().objects.removeAll()
    Lay().getCloudKit()
}
```

New `Lay.swift`:

```
  var objects = [Lay]()


func getCloudKit() {

    let now = NSDate()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TimeDate > %@", now)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "TimeDate", ascending: true)

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: “lay”, predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { 
            for lay in results! {
                let newlay = Lay()

                newLay.tColor = lay["tColor"] as! String
                newLay.timeDate = lay["TimeDate"] as! AnyObject
                newLay.matchup = lay["Matchup"] as! String

                let applicationDict = ["tColor" : newlay.tColor, "Matchup" : newlay.matchup]
                let transfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)

                self.objects.append(newlay)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                TableViewController().refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
                TableViewController().tableView.reloadData()
            })

        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

New `AppDelegate`:

```
private func setupWatchConnectivity() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}


private func sendUpdatedDataToWatch(notification: NSNotification) {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        if session.watchAppInstalled
        {
                let applicationDict = ["TColor" : Lay().tColor, "Matchup" : Lay().matchup]
                let transfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)
                NSLog("Transfer AppDelegate: %@", transfer)
                NSLog("Trans AppDelegate: %@", applicationDict)

                session.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(applicationDict)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you do `TableViewController()` or `Lay()` it is creating new instances of those classes, not accessing the existing instances that other objects are using.

Comment: Ah, so my whole thing is messed up, or there's some small change I need to make like doing a sharedInstance or something?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to your table view controller, probably through using an IBOutlet.

Comment: Ok. Add the IBOutlet in `TableViewController` and then reference that somehow in `Lay`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has `ViewController()` and `Lay()` throughout. This will create new instances of those objects. Therefore, although `refreshControl` is non-nil in your actual view controller, it will be nil in a newly created one.

By splitting out the `getCloudKit` function, you're allowing the view controller to just manage the view, and the new class to just manage Cloud Kit. This is good, so ideally your Cloud Kit controller should not know anything about the view controller. Therefore, getCloudKit shouldn't be calling reloadData. Instead, you could pass a closure into getCloudKit that gets called when the query finishes. Something along the lines of:

```
    func getCloudKit(completion completionHandler: (([Lay]) -> Void)?) {
         ...
         publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
            if error == nil { 
                ...
                if let completion = completionHandler {
                    completion(self.objects)
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
         }
    }
```

Then in ViewController:

```
    let layCloudKit = LayCloudKit()
    layCloudKit.getCloudKit(completion: { (objects) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.objects = objects
            self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
```

Note that I've assumed you would put the Lay Cloud Kit controller into a separate Swift file, as the Lay model class shouldn't need to know about Cloud Kit. If you want to put it in the same file as Lay, then you should mark the func as `static` or `class`, because you don't want to create a dummy instance of Lay just to call `getCloudKit`. In that case, you would call it using `Lay.getCloudKit` (ie. specifying the Lay class, rather than a Lay instance).

Comment: Going to give this a try and I'll let you know, thanks so much!!

Comment: Implementing right now, but stuck on what I believe must be an Xcode bug, because getting error "Use of unresolved identifier `LayCloudKit`" which doesn't make any sense that it wouldn't be finding that file. (I have looked at all of these steps to see if I did something wrong and nothing sticks out too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099111/swift-compiler-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-name)

Comment: It's unlikely to be a bug. You created a new file called `LayCloudKit.swift`, and inside it has `class LayCloudKit`?

Comment: Ah, no I didn't do the class part, ok retrying right now.

Comment: So I ran it, all the data looks like its logging, but nothing came up in the tableview.  So I ran it with breakpoints on the major functions, and the table functions are getting called before `getCloudKit`.  So I guess the table loads, but has no data so its empty, and then somehow I'm not getting the table to reload after.  So somehow I think it would be the completion handler thing isn't working to call reload?  Im sure Im missing something on my end, any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the table functions are being called before, because the completion handler is doing a reloadData, which will cause the table functions to be called again. It would be worthwhile including a print in numberOfRowsInSection to ensure that it becomes non-zero at some point.

Comment: Yeah in the `ViewController` code, I put breakpoints on every line, it runs the first two lines `let layCloudKit = LayCloudKit()` and `layCloudKit.getCloudKit(completion: {`, but doesn't run the last three lines that would refresh everything `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in` and `self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()` and `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: So it sounds like the completion is never running keeping in mind that it might take several seconds before it starts because it runs in the background. You should include a breakpoint on the call to the completion handler in LayCloudKit to ensure it is being run.

Comment: I just included a print in numberOfRowsInSection to ensure that it becomes non-zero at some point, and it is never non-zero.  It's always 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah I just put a breakpoint on the call to the completion handler in LayCloudKit to ensure it is being run, and it is.  Trying to figure this out, hmm

Comment: I'm assuming it's something to do with my `objects`.  I'm using `var objects = [Lay]()` at the top of `LayCloudKit.swift` and `ViewController.swift` so that must not work anymore maybe? Any thoughts?

Comment: You only want one. `getCloudKit` is updating the one in LayCloudKit, but nothing updates the one in ViewController, which is why its count is always zero. Ideally, `getCloudKit` should return the Lay array it created as part of the closure, so ViewController can use it. I will update my answer.

Comment: I see you're updated code and am implementing, quick question, which should I have `var objects = [Lay]()` at the top of: `ViewController` or `LayCloudKit`? (Because `self.objects` is being called in both, so I'm getting an error right now in both files if I remove `var objects = [Lay]()`)

Comment: It's ok to have that in both. The one in ViewController is just there as a placeholder until you update it in the closure for getCloudKit.

Comment: So then the only thing I'm getting errors on now is the `ViewController` code you posted above. The line: `layCloudKit.getCloudKit(completion: {` has the error `Cannot convert value of type () -> Void to expected argument type (({Lay]) -> Void)?`. And the line: `self.objects = objects` has the errors `() is not convertible to [Lay]` and `Cannot assign value of type() to type [Lay]`.  What are those about?

Comment: Whoops, I put the parameters on the wrong line - I have fixed it in the answer.