# Switch ViewController in swift,use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

XCode 7.3 Swift 2.2

I wanted to switch 3 ViewControllers:

I deleted the default ViewController.swift,and created a SwitchingViewController.swift(subclass of ViewController).
This is my code:

```
blueViewController = stroryboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Blue") as! BlueViewController
blueViewController.view.frame = view.frame
switchViewController(from: nil, to:blueViewController)
```

The problem is  "Use of unresolved identifier 'switchViewController'.

I tried to use the default ViewController.swift,and I still had the problem.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Well if it's called `SwitchingViewController` then use that rather than `switchViewController`. But I guess you method inside `SwitchingViewController` is called `switchViewController`, so you need to do `SwitchingViewController.switchViewController()`

Comment: Use SwitchingViewController instead of switchViewController?

Comment: Can you show how you declared your class and the method you are trying to call?

Comment: Where do you declare the func `switchViewController`?

Comment: I ceate  the project used single view,It cantains the default ViewController.swift and the storyboard, I deleted the ViewController.swift,then add SwitchingViewController.swift and BlueViewController.swift use Cocoa touch class,and I change the storyboard custom class to SwitchingViewController.I write that codes in SwitchingViewController.swift

Comment: but `switchViewController(from:to:)`, where is that declared? It's not a standard method, not in UIKit anyway.

Comment: I didn't declare the func switchViewController

Comment: Hope this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099111/swift-compiler-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-name

Comment: I fixed the issue by declared the func switchViewController

Comment: I thought it is a standard func.Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure everything you want to call has been declared yet. Since `switchViewController` is not provided by Apple you will need to create it yourself.

If you create the `func switchViewController(to:from:)` *inside* the `SwitchingViewController` class you can simply call it by typing `switchViewController(to:from:)` (with the values).
If you want to call it from another class, you need to call it *on* the class it's declared in, like this: `SwitchingViewController.switchViewController(to:from:)` (with the values).

I hope that helps :)

P.S.: If you want to do a simple transition to a ViewController, there are already methods written by Apple. If you use storyboards, you can for instance use `performSegueWithIdentifier("")`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're using the book iPhone Development with Swift? They define this function after using it; pretty silly idea on their part since it's going to throw an error and they didn't make it clear in the text that you write it later.

Flip a few pages and you will see that they define the below function. It might be different depending on your version of the book (mine is swift 2)

```
    private func switchViewController(from fromVC:UIViewController?, to toVC:UIViewController?){
    if fromVC != nil {
        fromVC!.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        fromVC!.view.removeFromSuperview()
        fromVC!.removeFromParentViewController()

    }

    if toVC != nil{
        self.addChildViewController(toVC!)
        self.view.insertSubview(toVC!.view, atIndex: 0)
        toVC!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

}
```